# Magento2 rest api get customer details and cart details as a admin authorization

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Magento2 rest api. If i am login as a admin user how can i get details of customer and it's cart items (items kept in cart for order later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i found it we can do it by help of rest/V1/carts/search?searchCriteria.

Comment: magento ver 1.9.2.3 My products API returns products, if i try with customer i am getting error, my url : http://192.168.1.65/anusthana/api/rest/customers error : https://snag.gy/0jbhTr.jpg  can u help me @arjun